# What libraries are there for reading/editing ID3s of mp3?

Tags: linux, libraries, c++, mp3, id3

I need a library to allow me to read and edit ID3 Tags
from C++ in Linux. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Taglib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) is quite feature rich.

It comes as C++ lib without dependencies to Qt or KDE libs. A C API is bundled (and there are a lot of other languages bindings available). A lot of projects (like amarok, juk, vlc ...) use this library.

The homepage contains some claims some advantages of taglib over id3lib (mainly performance).

Answer (score 1):

[id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) has an OO C++ interface you may like.  It is licensed under the LGPL.

The [MAD](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) MPEG audio decoder includes an ID3 manipulation component.  Since it is used as the underlying decoder for so many applications — there's a long list on the page I linked to — it may be in your distro's repository already.  It is GPL'd.

Answer (score 1):

- [libid3tag](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/)
- [taglib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html)

I used them for a tiny program I once wrote. Was quite easy to use.